# How to avoid duplicates on restoring sms in android?

Tags: java, android, sms

I'm doing backup and restore of sms, I'm able to do,but on restoring sms multiple times im getting the duplicates,which is not good, Im getting duplicates since im comparing with _Id(which is wrong),alternately I thought of comparing with number and body,but it is not efficient.

can anyone suggest solution with alternate comparision or if you know any other method to avoid duplicates,

thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to compare with number and SMS's received date "in milliseconds".

Comment: Kindly, mark my answer as a right answer :)